# Java, how could we write a file and save it from a stateless bean?

Tags: java, string, file, logging, javabeans

**I would need to write in a local file from a bean.**

I have studied:

[How do I create a file and write to it in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-write-to-it-in-java)

https://howtodoinjava.com/java-8/java-8-write-to-file-example/

And I have tried the code:

```
package beans;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;


@Stateless
public class ConviertePuntosNota {

    public String convertidor(int evaluacion) {

        try {

            List<String> lines = Arrays.asList("ConviertePuntosNota::convertidor::el usuario 9ntrodujo: " + evaluacion);
            Path file = Paths.get("log.txt");
            Files.write(file, lines, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));


            return evaluacion >= 5 ? "Apto" : "No apto";
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConviertePuntosNota.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return "ERROR";
    }
}
```

We would expect a file called log.txt in the same directoy as the bean is located.

Here wee see that in the hierarchy it does not show up:

[image]

Also if we try to search it in the project's directoy it does not appear:

[image]

In addition I tried to LOG the absolute path where it is being saved, adding:

Logger.getLogger(ConviertePuntosNota.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, null, file.toAbsolutePath().toString());

After Files.write, and we see an empty log:

[image]

Also it does not spawns on the hierarchy:

[image]

And it is not being found in the project:

[image]

**Coud you help me please, thank you**

Other post I have read before asking this question:

[FileIO from an stateless session bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917795/fileio-from-an-stateless-session-bean)

Comment: A bean is not located in a directory. It is located in a package,on the CLASSPATH. Your expectations don't make sense.

Comment: You will want to read about relative files, and current directories.  You have *no guarantee* about the location of log.txt.  Generally, it’s best for Java EE code to create files in a temporary directory, using [Files.createTempFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java EE programmers do not write to files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789597/java-ee-programmers-do-not-write-to-files)